# How do I parse the results from a Foursquare API call in PHP?

Tags: php, api, foursquare

so my problem is I'm calling the Foursquare API with this GET request:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b522afaf964a5200b6d27e3?client_id=".$client_id."&client_secret=".$client_secret
```

And I don't know how to parse the results to display what I need. Typing it into the browser with client ID and client secret gives a page of correct results so I know the URL is correct. The problem is in this part of my code:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
        foreach ($json->response->venue as $result)
        {
            echo $result->name.' - '.$result->location->address.' '.$result->location->city."<p />";
        }
```

Here $response is the result from the GET request which I am trying to parse as JSON and display the name, address and city variables. Does anyone know my problem? Maybe the result returned isn't JSON or I'm structuring my parse wrongly? Any help would be very gratefully received. Thanks!

Comment: Show us an example response from the API.

Comment: You never say what the actual problem is...

Comment: Doesn't Foursquare provide a specification or examples how to use their API?

Comment: I've done a lot of research and I can't find any examples of how to parse the result. @Mike B the error message is "Trying to get property of non-object in /nfs/mntI4/projectsite/O.Hind/profile.php on line 34", line 34 being the line inside the foreach block. An example of the section of the response I need is:

Comment: {"meta":{"code":200,"errorType":"deprecated","errorDetail":"Please provide an API version to avoid future errors.See http:\/\/bit.ly\/vywCav"},"response":{"venue":{"id":"4b522afaf964a5200b6d27e3","name":"The Woodville","contact":{"phone":"+442920397859","formattedPhone":"+44 29 2039 7859","twitter":"woodvillelovers"},"location":{"address":"1 - 5 Woodville Rd.","lat":51.49051570871893,"lng":-3.1805795431137085,"postalCode":"CF24 4DW","city":"Cardiff","state":"Wales","country":"United Kingdom"}

Comment: Anyone that reads this, the problem was with the 'foreach' block. I'm not sure why but if I just echo the results then it works fine how I'm parsing it in the above example.

Comment: Maybe it is just me but what is the problem? btw (hopefully) in the json above there is three `}` missed at the end..

Comment: The } are missing because it is just an example section of the JSON. The problem was that I could not parse the result properly but I took the echos out of the foreach block and it worked... so problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a "v=20120319" parameter in you call to the endpoint, otherwise the server will fail to know when you wrote the code and translate that to a certain API version it will use.

https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning